# What is the waveform of crystal oscillator and RTC and how can I monitor it?

Tags: oscillator

I'm trying to study crystal oscillators for STM32F103CBT6 and getting unexpected results or confused whether it is correct or not.

https://youtube.com/shorts/AmvjPQYd41o?feature=share

[image]

I expected that it gives square wave but it's sine; is that correct?

Here I want to add the output waveform of this crystal: [image]

Comment: What unexpected result are you getting?

Comment: What result do you expect and what do you get? Please make the question standalone so no external sites need to be referenced to answer the question.

Comment: @Justme the link is a video he has taken of the waveform he is measuring uploaded to YouTube

Comment: The load capacitors seem like they are not optimal. If they are calculated correctly, the stray capacitance for Y1 is 11pF?

Comment: @Electrocol:  The basic information needs to be in the question.  Screenshots of the video and an explanation of what is expected and what is shown.

Comment: @Electrocol Thanks for verifying, I kind of guessed it is a link to a video about question. Which is not the point of this site.

Comment: @Electrocol how can i calculated plz tell me

Comment: @Justme its output is sine wave not square wave

Answer (score 4):

Crystal oscillator waveforms at the crystal pins are sinusoidal.

Expecting square waves is wrong.

Comment: okay got it but still my smt not working properly as looks  crystal datasheet load capacitance is 18pf plz help me solve this mystery
crystal datasheet 
https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1359171.pdf

Comment: @AshuTamar Based on your description, I don't know what mystery you have and what is not working properly. What does "not working properly" means, what do you expect and what happens instead? Please understand that the crystals won't magically start oscillating by themselves, the MCU needs to run a program to turn on the oscillators before you can see any waveforms.

Comment: my doubt is that is this cap values are correct if not then how can i cross check it

Comment: @AshuTamar The capacitor values depend on the crystal. There is no other way than to look at which exact crystal you ordered to see what exact load capacitance it requires, to **guess** what capacitor values **should** be used, based on **assumed** stray capacitance from the **PCB design**. Also the 1 megaohm resistor is incorrect.

Comment: okay thanks for reply can plz tell me what resistor i should select for it

Comment: @AshuTamar No resistor. But your original question is now answered. If you have new questions, make them new questions and mark this as answered.